# Trouble Installing a wifi driver in 16.04 from Live USB

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, intel-wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my HP Envy laptop, which has an **Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 7265**. The "Wi-Fi Networks" option on the Panel is totally grayed out, and the Ubuntu doesn't seem to be recognizing any wi-fi connections -- not through my router, or my mobile hotspot.

I tried downloading [Intel's Linux-supported driver](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) so that I could install it in 16.04. I downloaded the .tgz file, extracted the contents, but I can't seem to copy the files into /lib/firmware -- I'm getting "**Error moving file: Permission denied**". I read somewhere that I might be able to change the permission with a command, but, alas, I'm a noob and I don't know how to make that happen.

After failing above, I tried to do (what I thought might be) the next best thing: To install the ndiswrapper hoping to at LEAST get the "Wi-Fi Networks" option to show available connections! I used old threads as an initial guide, but it didn't seem to apply to me because they mostly discuss the Broadcom network adapter (I have an Intel adapter).

So I unplugged my router and put the ethernet cable directly into my laptop, and then downloaded the latest version of ndiswrapper. After a long battle trying to unlock the "Universe" repository, I was finally able to make the suggested commands from [this thread](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper) and the install completed (DKMS: install completed). However, the "Wi-Fi Networks" option is still grayed out...

I lost a full day trying to solve this, any advice the community can provide to help me get Ubuntu to recognize my Wifi connections would be GREATLY appreciated!

Here is the output from @Pilot6 suggested command:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list; dmesg | grep iwl
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 61)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
[   14.139815] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[   14.139849] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[   14.139879] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2
[   14.140363] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[   14.198532] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   14.296435] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[   14.297448] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   14.297905] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   14.383466] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   14.616368] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   15.566013] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   15.566463] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   15.628602] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   15.629149] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   26.003733] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   26.004187] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   26.066654] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   26.067104] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  205.553892] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  205.554347] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  205.615895] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  205.616672] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

Comment: You do not need to install any drivers for this adapter. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list; dmesg | grep iwl` terminal command.

Comment: Installing Ndiswrapper will not help and most likely will cause much more problems.

Comment: @Pilot6, thank you for getting back to me. The output from the command you suggested is in my edited Question. Is there something I should do next (because my Wi-Fi Networks are still grayed out)?

Comment: I entered the exact command in your last comment and got an immediate output -- blacklist acer_wmi. I rebooted and, still, when I click on the wifi logo on my panel, the first four options are grayed out: Ethernet Network, disconnected, Wi-Fi Networks, and device not ready. "Connection Information" is also grayed out. I've been "trying Ubuntu without installing" from my USB -- does that make a difference? This comment was posted below.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by running in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

The Wi-Fi should work after a reboot.

Comment: That does make difference. The settings are not saved. Run `sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi && sudo rfkill unblock all`.

Comment: I couldn't connect to my wifi after I used your second command (for "Trying Ubuntu without installing"). So I installed ubuntu alongside Windows and your first command worked perfectly! Thank you for the help!

Comment: Do you know how I can save this setting (sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi && sudo rfkill unblock all) on a Live USB, so that I don't have to enter it in every time I boot from a Live USB in order to get my wifi signal unblocked?